# How to design a SQL Table for contract fees that are changing over time?

Tags: sql-server

I have a Table with thousands of trades. Each trade has a unique number and an exchange fee associated with. Then I have a calculated column that is the total cost (Fee, commission etc). I created a table with all the exchange fees but since they are changing a trade that was done before the change won't have the correct cost. I understand I have to add dates in the exchange table but should I name differently the exchange row? Like CME1, CME2, etc for all the fee changes? That doesn't seem a good SQL practice to me that is why I'm asking this question here.

## Table 1

```
Name        Cur Exc FillTime        ID    Price Side Size   TradeDate   Cost
Contract1   USD CME 8/1/14 5:32 AM  98123 1280  Long    1   8/1/2014    ?
Contract2   USD SFE 8/1/14 5:50 AM  98345 136   Long    1   8/1/2014    ?
```

## Table2

```
Exchange     Fees
CME          .50
CBOT         .60
```

Comment: Why can't you just persist the fee amount in the table first table? As fees change your app will use the new fee but historicially you see the fee as it was at the time.

Comment: Because this table is generated by a third party (the broker) from a csv.

Comment: Well, that leads to the solution, creating a full table with the cost as I receive a new csv from the broker. I was over complicating the problem.
Thank you very much